# How to show android Floating Window even on the Android 12's System Setting UI?

Tags: android, window, floating, android-12

After upgrade to target SDK 30, my AccessibilityService's Floating Window can't show on Android 12's System Setting UI. When enter the System Setting UI, Floating Window disappears. After quit the System Setting UI, Floating Window appears again.

I think it's a new limitation on android 12, before it's ok. Anyone have a workaround？ as I really need to show some tips while doing in AccessibilityService. thank you.

addView:

```
    if (mWindowManager != null) {
        mWindowManager.addView(buildAnimWindow(), buildLayoutParams());
    }
```

buildAnimWindow:

```
public AnimWindow buildAnimWindow() {
    AnimWindow res;

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    res = (AnimWindow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.anim_window, null);
```

buildLayoutParams:

```
public WindowManager.LayoutParams buildLayoutParams() {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams res;

    res = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
        res.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY;
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        res.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
    } else {
        res.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ForegroundService did the trick, tested ok on android 12:

MyForegroundService:

```
public class MyForegroundService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startForegroundFullOs(NOTIFY_ID, buildNotify());

        init();
    }

    private Context getContext() {
        return MyForegroundService.this;
    }

    private void init() {
        Logger.d(TAG, "BPFS::init");
        mContext = getContext();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
            if (MyService.getInstance() != null) {
                mWindowContext = MyAccessibilityService.getInstance();
            } else {
                mWindowContext = getContext();
            }
            mWindowManager = (WindowManager) mWindowContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        } else {
            mWindowContext = getContext();
            mWindowManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    public MyAnimWindow buildMyAnimWindow() {
        MyAnimWindow res;

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mWindowContext);
        res = (MyAnimWindow) inflater.inflate(R.layout.anim_window, null);
        Logger.d(TAG, "BPFS::buildMyAnimWindow, res = " + res);

        return res;
    }

    public WindowManager.LayoutParams buildLayoutParams() {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams res;

        res = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
            res.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY;
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            res.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
        } else {
            res.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
        }
        res.format = -3;
        res.width = -1;
        res.height = -1;

        res.flags = 0;
        res.flags |= 262144;
        res.flags |= 1024;
        res.flags |= 256;
        res.flags |= 8;
        res.flags |= Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        res.gravity = 51;
        res.x = 0;
        res.y = 0;

        return res;
    }

    
    public void showMyAnimWindow() {
        try {
            if (mWindowManager != null) {
                mWindowManager.addView(buildMyAnimWindow(), buildLayoutParams());
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

MyAccessibilityService:

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    private static MyAccessibilityService sInstance;
    public static MyAccessibilityService getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = MyAccessibilityService.this;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a new safety precaution meant to prevent apps from tampering with or intercepting actions from the Settings app.

Unless you are using an Accessibility service, "abusing" a `TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY` flag is not recommended. Per [the `TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY), albeit poorly written, such windows are only intended to allow an Accessibility service to intercept touch events without changing the views being introspected (examined).

Each user can opt in to displaying over Settings in the "Developer options" section of the Settings app (unlocked by tapping the "Build number" multiple times). Keep in mind that this is a blanket option, which allows any app with permission to display over other apps to also display over Settings.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I got it. but we are a clean cache app. It need to click CLEAR CACHE button in app info page, so an animation showing with floating window is friendly to users.

Comment: For every 100 apps with the best intentions, the one with malicious intent ruined it for everyone. In cases like this one, though, the opportunity for abuse outweighs even the most useful cases. Hopefully it does not prevent publishing, since Google tends to operate like a monarchy.